# What is the difference between setContentView and LayoutInflater?

Tags: android, layout, xml-parsing, android-lifecycle, layout-inflater

I am creating a tabs list with several fragments. 
I have noticed that, in the main activity, I used `setContentView` to get the layout xml and use `findViewById` to get the corresponding UI element config.

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup();
mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, android.R.id.tabcontent);
```

However, in the different fragment class, I have to use the inflater instead.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);
WebView myBrowser=(WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
```

And both function are used to get the layout xml to create an object, why is there a difference? Is the first one use during `onCreate`, and the second one during `onCreateView`? In what situation I should choose either of them?

Comment: Actually, `setContentView` internally use `LayoutInflator`. You can't call `findViewById` before calling `setContentView`, because the view hasn't been inflated yet.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`setContentView` is an `Activity` method only. Each `Activity` is provided with a `FrameLayout` with id `"@+id/content"` (i.e. the content view). Whatever view you specify in `setContentView` will be the view for that `Activity`. Note that you can also pass an instance of a view to this method, e.g. `setContentView(new WebView(this));` The version of the method that you are using will inflate the view for you behind the scenes.

Fragments, on the other hand, have a lifecycle method called `onCreateView` which returns a view (if it has one). The most common way to do this is to inflate a view in XML and return it in this method. In this case you need to inflate it yourself though. Fragments don't have a `setContentView` method

Activities and views both have a method called `findViewById()`. The activity version will search for a view with the given id inside of it's content view (therefore, internally, it will call `contentView.findViewById())`. This means that the contentView needs to be set before it becomes usable. Like `setContentView`, fragments don't have a method for `findViewById` (which makes sense, because there is no content view). Simply use `getView().findViewById()` instead for the same behaviour.

`LayoutInflater.inflate` just inflates and returns a view (you can use this anywhere). You still need to set that view as the content view within an Activity

Comment: Thanks for answering, also, is it necessary to get the xml file and create an object for it before findViewById? Since I found some example in offical doc is not. e.g. EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_address);