# Android: setContentView and LayoutInflater

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the difference between `setContentView` and `LayoutInflater`?
And whats the reason that we use `inflater` in custom `toast` and `setContentView` in custom `alertbox`?

Comment: I think here a good answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808177/difference-between-setcontentview-and-inflater

Answer (score 18):

You need to understand few things before,

In `Android` ,each `Activity` has one `ViewRoot` and usually one `Window` ,attached to it. However, a `SurfaceView` has its own window. So, if an `Activity` has a `SurfaceView` it will have more than one Window.

This activity is used for screen display occupying the entire Window. Views are attached to this Window. Every Window has a Surface and Surface uses `Canvas` to draw on the surface.The window the view is attached to owns the surface.

Basically `ViewRoot` is responsible for for collecting and dispatching the input and `View` is responsible for managing focus/key events, `Canvas` is only responsible for "drawing" operation using `onDraw()`.

`setContentView(View)` is a method exclusively available for `Activity`. Internally it calls the  `setContentView(View)` of `Window`. This method sets the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy. Calling this function "locks in" various characteristics of the window that can not, from this point forward, be changed. Hence it is called only once.

`LayoutInflater` is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects. Basically the purpose is to create view objects at runtime depending on the requirement.
Best example is the `AdapterViews` like `ListView`, `Spinner` etc, where a single view object corresponding to single record is created at run time depending on the number of records.

In case of `Toast`, `LayoutInflater` is used if the child view is going to be altered dynamically eg. changing the image at run time. If  no changes to child views are to be made then simplly `setView(View)` of toast is enough to set the layout view for toast.

Same as `Toast` is with the `AlertDialog` if you observe carefully.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It did help, thanks. But being a newbie I need to explore more.

Comment: Such answers are rare for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

setContentView internally uses Inflater to achieve it's functionality. It is a convenience method, which will take the responsibility of assigning parent / root view element for the layout being inflated. It also initializes the ActionBar.

Here is the Android source code:
Activity.java

```
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    getWindow().setContentView(layoutResID);
    initActionBar();
}
```

com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    if (mContentParent == null) {
        installDecor();
    } else {
        mContentParent.removeAllViews();
    }
    mLayoutInflater.inflate(layoutResID, mContentParent);
    final Callback cb = getCallback();
    if (cb != null && !isDestroyed()) {
        cb.onContentChanged();
    }
}
```

Regarding your 2nd question, we do use inflater in both custom toast and custom alert dialog.
e.g. Custom Toast creation:

```
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, 
(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root)));
```

e.g. Custom Alert Dialog creation:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null));
```

In case of Alert Dialog, we don't provide the root for the inflated layout, as the layout is added to FrameLayout element with id 'custom' as specified in the [alert_dialog.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml)

Answer (score 1):

`setContentView ()` is generally used to load an activity. `inflate` only Layout formed a view class object and, if necessary, then setContentView (view).
General activity via `setContentView (`) interface displayed, but how to control layout is set to operate in non-activity, which need `LayoutInflater` dynamic loading. For example when you use adapter class for spinner probably you have to use `LayoutInflater`.

Answer (score 1):

**setContentView() :** this method set your background layout.

**LoayoutInflater:** suppose if you use listview and your need show list 10 item.then layoutIflat do work for show 10 item

**inflater:** it is need for your layou design, keep value for 
layoutInflat

**Custom Toast:** it is how your string output.custom toast means your wish for design output.stylist output show.

sorry bro i also did not know alertbox.Thank you vary much