# Android Studio: App doesn't start with implemented Anonymous Java Class

Tags: java, android, xml, actionlistener

I caught the error message

> "5-14 12:39:13.104 2518-2518/com.example.fdai3744.neueleereapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                           Process: com.example.fdai3744.neueleereapp, PID: 2518                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ..."

and here's my Java Code

```
package com.example.fdai3744.neueleereapp;

import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public Button button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //Button
        public TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1); // Textview

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Here I add the ActionListener for my button

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    text1.setText("Button 1 wurde geklickt!");
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

If I start my App the emulator throws an error message "App has stopped". How should I prevent this error?

Comment: isn't there any "caused by: another exception" in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caused by

```
 public Button button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //Button
    public TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1); // Textview
```

never assign view before setContentView() is called

your modified code

```
package com.example.fdai3744.neueleereapp;

import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public Button button_1;
        public TextView text1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //Button
           text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1); // Textview

            button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Here I add the ActionListener for my button

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    text1.setText("Button 1 wurde geklickt!");
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, your view hierarchy needs to be alive before your retrieve individual `View`s from it and the method `setContentView()` brings it to life(or instantiates it).

How?

> `setContentView(View)` is a method exclusively available for Activity.
>   Internally it calls the `setContentView(View)` of Window. This method
>   sets the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed
>   directly into the activity's view hierarchy. Calling this function
>   "locks in" various characteristics of the window that can not, from
>   this point forward, be changed. Hence it is called only once.

**So, instead of initializing the Views as instance variables, instantiate them inside `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`.**

Also read: [Android: setContentView and LayoutInflater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903033/android-setcontentview-and-layoutinflater)